# triggering 2 flows in one process builder error?

Tags: process, builder

I'm getting a process builder error, in the process I'm triggering (Or possibly triggering) 2 flows in the same process. I'm assuming this is the error, however trying different solutions (Like running subflows instead) and still not working I'd love to get input on how to debug the specific reason for this error. Error message and screenshot of process builder below:

Error element myRule_1_A1 (FlowActionCall).
An error occurred when executing a flow interview.
Flow Details
Flow API Name: IR_LOI_Alert
Type: Record Change Process
Version: 13
Status: Active
Org: --------- A/S (....)

Flow Interview Details
Interview Label: IR_LOI_Alert-13_InterviewLabel
Current User: ....... (0051t000003IjgW)
Start time: 10-03-2020 15:00
Duration: 0 seconds
How the Interview Started
.................. (0051t000003IjgW) started the flow interview.
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
myVariable_old = Case_Product__c (a015J000002yuXsQAI)
myVariable_current = Case_Product__c (a015J000002yuXsQAI)
DECISION: myPreWaitDecision_myWait_myRule_9
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: myPreWaitRule_myWait_myRule_9
Outcome conditions:
{!formula_myRule_9} (false) Equals true

Default outcome executed.
ASSIGNMENT: myWaitAssignment_myWait_myRule_9
{!cancelWaits} Add myWait_myRule_9
Result
{!cancelWaits} = "[myWait_myRule_9]"
DECISION: myDecision
Outcome executed: myRule_1
Outcome conditions:
{!formula_myRule_1} (true) Equals true
SALESTARGET_RELATIONS_FLOW (FLOWS): myRule_1_A1
Inputs:
RecordId = {!myVariable_current.Id} (a015J000002yuXsQAI)
Error Occurred: An error occurred when executing a flow interview.
Salesforce Error ID: 1514190932-317309 (-705002586)

[image]

Comment: It seems that error is in flow. It is impossible to give more details since there are not enough of input. One of the approach could be opening debug logs -- sometimes more information about nature of an exception will be shown there

Comment: Thanks for your response.I've debugged the flows individually with no errors on several records, which is why i suspect that it could be the 2 flows running simultaneously causing the error.

Comment: Debugged flows again, found an error in the flow and deployed - seems to be working. Thank you